# How to get an icon using layer list with a rectangle shape with one edge cut off?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-icons, layer-list

I am trying to set an imageview with an icon having one edge of the rectangle cut off; the bottom right edge specifically.

I guess it can be achieved with `layer-list` but how?

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks 
[image: something like this image here]

Comment: simple way is take image for that

Comment: @Nilesh yep I know right but I don't really have a choice for now..is there a workaround for this anyhow?

Comment: use a custom class extending `BitmapDrawable`

Answer (score 2):

Path.onRoundRect() will not support different sizes for each corner. Better u design a image as u want and use it.

Otherwise u can design rounded rectangle like this...

```
<layer-list
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item >
    <shape 
         android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid
            android:color="#ff00ff"></solid>
        <corners
            android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:topRightRadius="10dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"></corners>
    </shape>
</item>
<item 
    android:drawable="@android:drawable/ic_btn_speak_now">

</item>
```

Comment: I am trying with the same concept but not successful so far. Thanks for replying though..